# Is it possible to control the volume of my local notifications from my app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I have an app that notify my user periodically using repeat intervals. Now my app users are asking me to allow them to control the volume of the notification differently from others. (Mostly lower than the current level of the device).

I was wondering if there is a way to do that?

Comment: It doesn't show how the user would be able to adjust the volume as they require

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use different sound files for different volume. For example five files alarm1.aiff, alarm2.aiff ... alarm5.aiff. User select a volume (1 to 5) level in your app's preferences and then the notification will use the corresponding file.

That way is the same as using options to select alarm sound. But only varying volume.

Comment: Doesn't the system adjust the sound volume in order to observe the sound limits (protection) and guarantee an even user experience?

Comment: Nice! That's what I had in mind, however, will the user be able to choose the sound file within the `UILocalNotification.soundName = @"xxx.wav";` ?

Comment: @user1949873 I don't understand your question. The user don choose the  sound file. He selects a level in your app and you, programmatically set soundName.

Comment: I understand that he will select the level and that would lead the code to a different sound file which has different volume. if you can show me this code I'll mark it the right answer... is it just an if condition to `notif.soundName` itself, or within the `soundName`?

Comment: @user1949873 Actually, you let the user select a level. Then, you select the soundName matching the level and you play it using `AVAudioPlayer`.

Comment: @IsaMeg please post an elaborated code over here and get the right answer. [AVAudioPlayer] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867356/is-there-a-way-to-let-the-user-choose-the-sound-for-local-notification)

Comment: Thank you very much :) but patapple already posted one.

Answer (score 3):

**Unfortunately no** (public) API give you control over the notification sound volume.

Both `UILocalNotification` popups and sounds are managed by a system process. That process uses the user's sound volume preferences, it also checks wether or not the the device is in silent mode, etc. before playing a sound. This is coherent in a way.

**So, you have two options:**

1. Tell your users have to globally adjust the volume for all
   notification or put their phone in silence mode.
2. Handle the notification yourself and play the sound
   right from your app (to achieve that, you will need to keep your app running in
   the background).

**Here is a snippet for the latter solution:**

```
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:YOUR_SOUND_URL error:&error];
[audioPlayer setVolume:YOUR_DESIRED_VOLUME];
if (audioPlayer == nil)
{
    NSLog([error description]);             
}
else 
{
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

*Note: replace `YOUR_SOUND_URL` and `YOUR_DESIRED_VOLUME` by appropriate values.*

**Also worthy of mentioning is this discussion:** 
[Sounds in UILocalNotification louder than AVAudioPlayer at max volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549067/sounds-in-uilocalnotification-louder-than-avaudioplayer-at-max-volume)

Comment: Thanks for writing such a detailed answer. But the only thing I am not able to understand that how are you planning to keep the app active in the background even if the app is explicitly killed by the user?