# is there a way to let the user choose the sound for local notification?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I have an app that has 64 local notifications with repeat intervals. So I can't add more notifications, or otherwise, I'd need the user to open the app again for a reschedule.

I was wondering if I'm able to let the user choose the file with in this code:

```
notif.soundName = @"xxx.wav";
```

so they can choose `xyz.wav` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can let the user choose the sound between some that are already in your project or you could also let him take a song from the music library.

Update:
If the files are already in your Xcode project, you can create a NSString or a int value to store the user choose. You create a button that let the user choose a sound. You connect this button to change the string or int value. Then you create and if statement that check this string or int and change properly the UILocalnotification sound.

```
int soundNumber;

- (IBAction)chooseSoundName {
   soundNumber = 1;
}

- (void)loadSoundName {
   if(SoundNumber == 1) {
       localNotification.soundName = @"first.wav";
   }
}
```

Then you call the loadSoundName method (or you could integrate it into another method).

Hope it helps

Comment: Please show me how would I do that? Is it only an if else condition that leads to the code `notif.soundName = @"xxx.wav";` or there is a specific code with a property I can set?

Comment: Do you want to use sounds that are already in your Xcode project?

Comment: Local Notifications does not allow the sounds from music library, You can only assign a sound present in your application resource bundle.

Comment: I agree. If the sound is in your application resource bundle and you let the user choose one of them, you can still set your sound.